# Normal distribution, and the exponent -(x-u)^2, and rationale for why "normal distribution" curve is so particularly good

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

The "normal distribution" is often described as if it were one of the great wonders of the world, or something like that. I am unable to see why. I definitely agree things in the universe, like the length of human beings, tend to be centered around an average value, and that an average deviation from that center can be calculated. But, the mean absolute deviation does that pretty well, without involving the squaring of the distance of each variable's distance from the average, (x-u)^2. The fact that squaring is superior to just using the absolute value, is not initially apparent to me.

Diving into how curves that have a "bell shape" can be created mathematically, taking some base like e to the power of the absolute value of x, e^-|x|, creates a pretty ugly  and spiky curve. Adding an exponent, like e^-|x|^2 or e^-|x|^1.5 or e^-|x|^3, flattens the spike. With e^-|x|^2, the absolute value operation can be skipped, leaving e^-x^2. This is what the "normal distribution" uses, and it also subtracts the average to center the curve around that value, as e^-(x-u)^2.

Given that a curve e^-(x-u)^2 is chosen to be used, also calculating the root mean square deviation, instead of mean absolute deviation, seems like it could be beneficial, since it is proportional to (x-u)^2 (the variance is proportional, the mean square deviation. )

So assuming the curve e^-(x-u)^2, or e^-(x-u)^2/(2s^2), I can see why the "standard deviation" format is chosen instead of mean absolute deviation.

But, I do not see why e^-x^2 is somehow the "perfect match" for phenomena in the universe. It seems a bit arbitrary. It seems like there might be many other ways to create that "bell" shape.

Is there some easy-to-understand rationale, that is easy and intuitive but not too dumb to be meaningless (so easy in a smart sense, a clever explanation) for why exactly the "normal distribution" equation is uniquely suited to fit how things tend to be distributed and for probability and frequency distributions? An example of an "easy" explanation is [3Blue1Brown's explanation of the Fourier Transform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The Central Limit Theorem is the usual justification.

Comment: Attributed to Henri Poincaré  "Everyone is sure of this [that errors are normally distributed], Mr. Lippman told me one day, since the experimentalists believe that it is a mathematical theorem, and the mathematicians that it is an experimentally determined fact." cited in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Henri_Poincar%C3%A9#Quotes)

Comment: Thanks for comments. They leave me with the same feeling I had before, but with more opinions behind that :) A quick glimpse at Abraham de Moivre's first demonstration of "central limit theorem" from random Google search (https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Moivre,_Abraham_de) shows he seemed to be able to show that limit for binomial distribution as n --> infinity  was e^-x^2/2. The exponent x^2, to me, makes it logical to work with the root mean square deviation instead of mean absolute deviation, and from that I could see why everything is squared in such an unintuitive way.

Comment: @Henry Thanks, I already knew that since a week thanks to my younger brother who has a masters degree in math and told me that. But have not been able see why myself. I noticed the exponent in curve that seemed somewhat natural to use, was very similar to the format of variance. And that is the best thing I have to hold onto for why root mean square deviation would be so much more natural than mean absolute deviation (that is more natural to me as a "beginner". )